# UITableViewCell with clear background and colored contentView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to create a "fake" spacing around my `UITableViewCell` and I'm doing so by inset-ing the contentView's frame by 10 each [I actually am adding a custom view on top of the contentView and inset it by 10]. It looks like the contentView is the only visible view. This looks really well and I'm also setting and adjusting the frame of `selectedBackgroundView` for my cell so that selecting will only select the "visible" area.

Now the issue of doing so is the following:

If I select a cell, it flashes with `UIColor.darkGray` as specified by my `selectedBackgroundView`.
Then for a short period of time within the animation my cell background is invisible entirely before it flashes back to how it was.
This way the animation does not look fluent.

This applies to the content view:

1. Background Color
2. darkGray (selectedBackgroundView)
3. Clear Color
4. Background Color

Does anybody know if I can fix this behaviour while keeping selection to be a thing?

I created a gif out of the animation: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQME3.jpg

Here is my code:

```
class BasicTableViewCell : UITableViewCell {
    public var basicContentView: UIView = UIView(frame: .zero)

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        self.tintColor = UIColor.white

        self.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

        self.basicContentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.barTintColor
        self.basicContentView.layer.masksToBounds = false
        self.basicContentView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
        self.basicContentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.contentView.addSubview(self.basicContentView)

        self.basicContentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10.0).isActive = true
        self.basicContentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -10.0).isActive = true
        self.basicContentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.topAnchor, constant: 10.0).isActive = true
        let bottomConstraint = self.basicContentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -10.0)
        bottomConstraint.priority = UILayoutPriority(999)
        bottomConstraint.isActive = true

        let selectedView: UIView = UIView(frame: .zero)
        selectedView.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
        selectedView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
        selectedView.layer.masksToBounds = false
        self.selectedBackgroundView = selectedView
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        // only for selectedBackgroundView, contentView raised other issues
        let contentViewFrame = self.contentView.frame
        let insetContentViewFrame = contentViewFrame.inset(by: UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10))
        self.selectedBackgroundView?.frame = insetContentViewFrame
    }
}
```

I already know what the issue is, based on: [Apples explanation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623226-selectedbackgroundview)
`selectedBackgroundView` is added to `contentView` and then fades away before being removed from the `contentView` and then `basicContentView` is suddenly visible again which causes the bug.

## Here is my fix

```
override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        if selected {
            self.basicSelectedBackgroundView.alpha = 1.0
            self.basicContentView.insertSubview(self.basicSelectedBackgroundView, at: 0)
        } else {
            guard self.basicSelectedBackgroundView.superview != nil else {
                return
            }
            if animated {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, options: .allowUserInteraction, animations: {
                    self.basicSelectedBackgroundView.alpha = 0.0
                }) { (finished: Bool) in
                    if finished {
                        self.basicSelectedBackgroundView.removeFromSuperview()
                    }
                }
            } else {
                self.basicSelectedBackgroundView.alpha = 0.0
                self.basicSelectedBackgroundView.removeFromSuperview()
            }
        }
    }
```

I am overriding setSelected and animate it myself.

Comment: Could you share your implementation of `didSelect` method ?

Comment: I added a bug explanation. I know the bug by now but I need to fix it

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to override `setSelected` in your cell. For example:

```
override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    //If we don't get the contentView's backgroundColor here and then reset it after the call to super.setSelected, the contentView's backgroundColor will "disappear" when the cell is selected
    let contentViewColor = contentView.backgroundColor
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    contentView.backgroundColor = contentViewColor
}
```

When a cell is selected, the backgroundColor properties for ALL subviews of the cell are set to the selection color, which overwrites any backgroundColor properties you have set yourself. So you might need to  manually set the backgroundColor of your contentView here to get the behaviour you want.

Comment: yeah I thought about this as well. Will need an adapted version for my code